# Android: db.update() issue

Tags: android, sqlite

how do I update all row in a table ? In my code, I use a non-primary key `stat` for some matters and I found it hard to understand why can't I solve this little problem I have.

Here is my table:

```
______________________________________________
|   _id   |   Pname   |   escr   |   stat    |
|_________|___________|__________|___________|
|    1    |   Andrew  |    15    |     0     |
|    2    |    John   |    12    |     0     |
|    3    |    Ian    |    10    |     1     |
```

In my table, I need to make the column `stat` of all entries into `0`.
So I made my code like this;

```
    public int ClearRecentPlayer(ClearRecPlayerData pd) {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();

        ContentValues v = new ContentValues();
        v.put(COLUMN_NAME_PSTATS, pd.getRest());

        return db.update(TABLE_NAME_PLAYER, v, null,null);
        }

//"UPDATE player SET stat =?" right??
```

Then I called my method;

```
.
.
.
DataConn myDb = new DataConn(this);
myDb.ClearRecentPlayer(new ClearRecPlayerData(0));
.
.
.
```

ClearRecPlayerData.java

```
public class ClearRecPlayerData {

    int _rest;

    public ClearRecPlayerData(){
    }

    public ClearRecPlayerData(int rest){
        this._rest = rest;
    }

    public int getRest(){

        return this._rest;
    }
    public void setRest(int rest){

        this._rest = rest;
    }
}
```

and then after all of these, I found out it has done nothing at all. Not even what I expected. :-(

**EDIT:** 
after that update, I made another class;

```
myDb.RegisterPlayer(new Playerdata(passPname,0,1)); //inserts perfectly fine
```

that will insert a new row in my table;

```
    ______________________________________________
    |   _id   |   Pname   |   escr   |   stat    |
    |_________|___________|__________|___________|
    |    1    |   Andrew  |    15    |     0     |
    |    2    |    John   |    12    |     0     |
    |    3    |    Ian    |    10    |     1     | <--should be 0.
.
.
.
    |    4    |    Pia    |     0    |     1     | <---newly inserted(sample)
```

and then I will call a row in the table where col `stat = '1'`

```
public List<Pdeasyupdate> getScoreEasy() {
    List<Pdeasyupdate> pdu = new ArrayList<Pdeasyupdate>();

    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    String selectQuery = "SELECT  * FROM " + TABLE_NAME_PLAYER + " WHERE "+
            COLUMN_NAME_STAT +" = '1'";

    Cursor c = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);

    if (c.moveToFirst()) {
        do {
            Pdeasyupdate ed = new Pdeasyupdate();
            ed.setePname(c.getString(1));
            ed.seteEscr(Integer.parseInt(c.getString(2)));
            ed.seteHscr(Integer.parseInt(c.getString(3)));
            ed.seteDscr(Integer.parseInt(c.getString(4)));
            // Adding contact to list
            pdu.add(ed);
        } while (c.moveToNext());
        db.close();
    }
```

and so, expect that the newly inserted row will be called because the other row has already `stat = 0`.

the BAD news is; it returns `null` in all

```
    Integer.parseInt(c.getString()));
```

Comment: *I found out it has done nothing at all.* how? this code should work. maybe the problem is in other place

Comment: like where? I have declared a static `COLUMN_NAME_STATS` string with the same value 'stats'. So I change the other one into `stat` which is this one but still have the same error.

Comment: First how, how did you check that it's doesn't work? Other places like do not refresh, put there 1 in some other place, etc.

Comment: i'll update my post for the next logic I made.

Comment: ClearRecentPlayer should returns number of affected rows ... so it should be equal to rows number ... if it's equal then problem is not here , end of story

Comment: pardon me for my lack of knowledge but, how may I notice that?

Comment: do not use getString for number ... use getInt ... next: `SELECT *` then using index as hardcoded value is asking for a trouble

Comment: the `getString` line is for the pname. no problem to that, I suppose.. may I ask your suggestion please, mr. @Selvin

Answer (score 0):

You can do exec

```
db.execSQL("UPDATE my_table SET stat = 0 ");
```

Also if you still didnt see any changes, probably there is problem with transactions, so try this

```
db.beginTransaction();
try {
    db.execSQL("UPDATE my_table SET stat = 0 ");
    db.setTransactionSuccessful();
} catch {
    //Error in between database transaction 
} finally {
    db.endTransaction();
}
```

Comment: i'll give it a try.

Comment: returns null but no internal error... means `db.execSQL()` did not work. :-(

Comment: db.exexSQL() always returns null. Or Select query returned null after this?

Comment: the selection after this.